# Unable to filter values in Python which has been imported as 'pandas.core.series.Series' datatype

Tags: python-3.x

Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/independence-days

I am unable to filter observations for 'Belgium' from independence-day dataset.

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
path = FilePath

#My hypothesis was that the filtering for Country name is not working since its not a String data type, hence tried converting it to 'str' while importing.
readFile = pd.read_csv(path, dtype={'Country': str}, engine = 'python')

df = pd.DataFrame(readFile)
columnNames = list(df.columns.values)
df = pd.DataFrame(readFile, columns = columnNames)
print(type(df['Country']))
countryName = 'Belgium'
df2 = df[df['Country'] == countryName]
print(df2)

Output: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Country, Date of holiday, Year celebrated, Event celebrated, Name 
of holiday]
Index: []

# I tried data type conversion for the country column based on previous 
#recommendation but they don't give me the desired output. 
#Things I tried.

1) df['Country'].astype('str')
2) df['Country'] = df['Country'].astype(str)

Data Snippet
|Country     | Date of holiday | Year celebrated | Event celebrated |Name of holiday|

|Afghanistan |08-19 August     |1919         |Independence from the United Kingdom in 1919.|Afghan Independence Day|
|Algeria     |07-05 July       |1962         |Independence from France in 1962.        |Independence Day (Algeria)|
```

PS: I am new to Python as well as Stackoverflow. Please assist.

Comment: Would you include an excerpt from your datafile?

Comment: @user2314737 Please let me know in case the additional information helps.

Comment: @user2314737: I found the issue with this. My original hypothesis around datatype for country column was incorrect. It has nothing to do with column datatype in this case.

Comment: Here post importing the file the contents within country column were changing. There was a /0 which got appended before every country because of which the  code countryName = 'Belgium' | df2 = df[df['Country'] == countryName] was returning blank. After i change it it worked fine.